# Flat families and section of family of curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface. Let $L$ be an ample line bundle on $X$. Consider $Y=\{(x,C) : C\in |L|, x\in C\}\subset X\times |L|$. Then $p_2:Y\longrightarrow |L|$ is a family of curves over $|L|$ right?

1) Is this a flat family? How do we check that it is a flat family?

2) Does $p_2:Y\longrightarrow |L|$ admit a section? That is to every $C$ we need to associate a point of $C$ in a continuous manner. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 1), use the fact that $Y$ is a Cartier divisor on $X\times |L|=Z$ and the fibers of $p_2$ are one dimensional. We have an exact sequence, $0\to \mathcal{O}_Z(-Y)\to\mathcal{O}_Z\to \mathcal{O}_Y\to 0$. Tensoring with $k(x)$ for $x\in |L|$, the sequence remains exact and so the Tor is zero, showing $\mathcal{O}_Y$ is flat over $|L|$.

2) is false. For example, take $|L|$ to be the quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^2$. If $p_2$ had a section, it would mean at least that every fiber has  one point which is reduced since the section meets every fiber once. But, there are double lines in the fiber.

Comment: Thanks Mohan! But for 2) if we restrict to smooth curves in $|L|$ it will not be a problem right?

Comment: It will still be a problem. In general, sections are difficult in such a situation. If the line bundle had a base point, you can hope to get one.

Comment: Ah then we cannot get a Poincaré' line bundle on this family of curves?

Comment: Not  in general. Picard group of $Y$ tends to be small.

Comment: Ah thanks, is there some reference where I can read about this?

Comment: Intersection theory! The closed point is not a cartier divisor. In the above example of mine, $Y$ is smooth and thus a section is a Cartier divisor on it. So, the section will meet each fiber exactly once.

Comment: Dear Mohan, I have withdrawn my previous comment, which indeed did not apply to the situation. Sorry about that. Your example is very nice and it is certainly true that you can't find a section of $p_2$  .

Comment: @Mohan, I have a doubt, how can I show that $Y$ is a Cartier divisor in $X\times |L|$? And will it not be a Weil divisor too?

Comment: $Z$ is smooth, $Y$ is pure codimension one, so it is a Cartier divisor too. On smooth variteies, there is no distinction between Cartier and Weil divisors.